# How do you print out data from a Firebase database and append it to HTML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a jQuery script to print out values on my Firebase database. Here is the database code:

```
firebase.initialize({
    projectName: "vibetune"
});

var database = firebase.database();

var vibes = {
    Upbeat:{
        tunings:["E Standard", "E Flat Standard", "Drop D"],
        tuningSongs:["Everlong", "My Generation", "Jailhouse Rock"]
    },
    Sad:{
        tunings:["Drop D Flat", "DADGAD","DAEAC#E"],
        tuningSongs:["Micheline", "Lost in Hollywood", "Emo Song"]
    },
    Mellow:{
        tunings:["CGCGCD", "FACGCE", "Open G"],
        tuningSongs:["An Island", "Never Meant", "Daughter"]
    },
    Heavy:{
        tunings:["D Standard", "Drop C", "AGCFAD"],
        tuningSongs:["Blood and Thunder", "Monster", "Alpha"]
    },
    Experimental:{
        tunings:["Ostritch Tuning", "Open C", "Nick Drake Tuning"],
        tuningSongs:["Venus in Furs", "Moon Song", "Pink Moon"]
    }
};

for(var vibe in vibes){
    database.ref(vibe).set({
        tunings:vibes[vibe].tunings,
        tuningSongs:vibes[vibe].tuningSongs
    })
}
```

What I'm *trying* to do is take the strings in the arrays of the `tunings` and `tuningSongs` key onto `<li>` tags (i.e. make each value in the array an `<li>` tag in a `<ul>`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vibe Tune</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200..700&display=swap')</style>
        <script src="https://static.codehs.com/cdn/latest/chsfirebase/chsfirebase.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img class="pgimg" alt="upbeat" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AEYmBYSy_Rh7voLgctZUSBK5N3plPbZ9NWRHK4kozjAZEsAoeWZ_7zkDXtHQZIOHHbRsdQJ-DZszI_ccNCqhODnDx__wPql5pQ=s2560?source=screenshot.guru">
       <h1 class="pgtitle">Upbeat Tunings</h1>
       <h3 class="pgsub">Tunings for a happy vibe</h3>
       
       <div id="upbeat">
           <h3>Tunings</h3>
           <ul id="tunings">
               
           </ul>
           
           <h3>Songs for Tunings</h3>
           <ul id="songsfortunings">
               
           </ul>
       </div>
       
       <h4><a href="index.html"><i>Back to Home</i></a></h4>
       
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               firebase.initialize({
                    projectName: 'vibetune'
               });
                              
                //function updateUpbeatData(){
                    var database = firebase.database();
                    var upRef = database.ref("Upbeat");
                    
                    console.log("attemping to fetch data...");
                    
                    upRef.on("value", function(snapshot){
                        console.log("Snapshot: ", snapshot.val());
                        var nodeData = snapshot.val();
                        
                        if(nodeData != null){
                            console.log("Node data exists: ", nodeData);
                            $("#tunings").empty();
                            $("#songsfortuning").empty();
                        
                            if(nodeData.tunings){
                                nodeData.tunings.forEach(function(tuning){
                                    $("#tunings").append("<li>" + tuning + "</li>");
                                });
                            }
                            if (nodeData.tuningSongs){
                                nodeData.tuningSongs.forEach(function(song){
                                    $("#songsfortunings").append("<li>" + song + "</li>");
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("No data found at the specified reference.");
                        } 
                    });
                //}
               //updateUpbeatData();
            });
       </script>
       <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my HTML (sorry if it's a bit messy, that was a result of my trying desperately to fix it). You can also see the `<ul>` tags I'm trying to fill. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What logging output do you get when you `console.log(tuning)` inside the `forEach` callback?

Comment: Nothing. :( The console says that snapshot is null and idk why.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see the problem then. Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the top of the data in the Firebase console?